# UIScrollView in SwiftUI does not line up with full screen

Tags: swiftui, uiscrollview, scrollview

I am trying to make a vertical scroll view similar to Tiktok and have made a custom scroll view using UIScrollView. I am having a problem getting the scroll view to align with the screen. It seems to be something with how the scroll view is interacting with the safe area.

The full code is shown below.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
        
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                CustomScrollView(screenWidth: geo.frame(in: .local).width, screenHeight: geo.frame(in: .local).height)
            }
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 75)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct ScrollContents: View {
    
    var screenWidth: CGFloat
    var screenHeight: CGFloat
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.green)
                .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
            Rectangle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        }
    }
}

struct CustomScrollView : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    var screenWidth: CGFloat
    var screenHeight: CGFloat
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return CustomScrollView.Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIScrollView{
        
        let view = UIScrollView()
        
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: ScrollContents(screenWidth: screenWidth, screenHeight: screenHeight))
        
        view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = true
        childView.view.insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea = true
        childView.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: screenHeight, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight)
        view.contentSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight*3)
        
        view.addSubview(childView.view)
        view.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        view.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        
        view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        view.isPagingEnabled = true
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
                
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIScrollView, context: Context) {
        
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject,UIScrollViewDelegate{
        
        var parent : CustomScrollView
        
        init(parent : CustomScrollView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            
        }
    }
}
```

When the app opens, the view lines up perfectly, but when I scroll down there is a slight offset, as shown below.

[view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyBYq.gif)

If I change the UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior to "always" on line 68, the scroll effect works perfectly, but this adds an extra paging effect for the safe area at the top, as shown below.

[view.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTI9w.gif)

Does anyone know how I can get this effect?